# Magento 2.4.4 customer grid not working

Tags: eav-attributes, magento2.4.4, magento-2-commerce

I've seen this error before and I believe i've fixed it in the past but i can't seem to resolve it atm. So the Argument 1 passed must be of the type array, null given, called in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121.

I think it something to do with an eav attribute related to customers. Not sure how to determine which attribute it may be because we have alot.

I did see a possible quick fix/patch that said to do this but i know it goes against magento values by editing the core.

```
\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\ConfigFactory
```

in code you have line like this

```
$this->configFactory->create();
```

but should be

```
$this->configFactory->create($optionsData);
```

---

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config, Argument 1 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config, Argument 1 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]
#3 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:642]
#4 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php:98]
#5 Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataConverter->createMetadataAttribute() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/AddressMetadata.php:77]
#6 Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\AddressMetadata->getAttributeMetadata() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/AddressMetadata.php:109]
#7 Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\AddressMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CachedMetadata.php:85]
#8 Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CachedMetadata->getAllAttributesMetadata() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/AttributeRepository.php:90]
#9 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\AttributeRepository->getList() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns.php:112]
#10 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns->prepare() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#11 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#12 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/amasty/orderattr/Model/ResourceModel/Value/Plugin/Order/Grid/Columns.php:57]
#13 Amasty\Orderattr\Model\ResourceModel\Value\Plugin\Order\Grid\Columns->aroundPrepare() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#14 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#15 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Interceptor.php:23]
#16 Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Interceptor->prepare() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:164]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:161]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:142]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:93]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:365]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:32]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:65]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:271]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:896]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]
#29 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php:28]
#30 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#31 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#32 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#33 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:23]
#34 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:151]
#36 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#37 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#38 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:145]
#39 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#40 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#41 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:32]
#42 Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:245]
#43 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:212]
#44 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#45 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#46 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#47 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#48 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#49 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#50 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#51 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
</pre>
```

Has anybody else ran into this issue and know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have in some module a datapatch that tries to add this eav attribute, probably the definition of the attribute doesn´t have the array standard to create the necessary key => values to pass in the constructor method, example:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function apply()
{
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_code', [
        "label" => "my custom attr",
        "type"  => "varchar",
         ...
    ]);
}
```

In other wise you can set a breakpoint in the line that throws your error vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121, and see the arguments that the function createObject($type, $args) this can tell you more detail about the especific attribute that is going wrong

Comment: Thank you i'll test out a breakpoint.